# Hadoop: reciprocal of hdfs dfs -text

Tags: hadoop, command-line, hdfs, hadoop2

In Hadoop, the `hdfs dfs -text` and `hdfs dfs -getmerge` commands allow one to easily read contents of compressed files in HDFS from the command-line, including piping to other commands for processing (e.g. `wc -l <(hdfs dfs -getmerge /whatever 2>/dev/null)`).

Is there a reciprocal for these commands, allowing one to push content to HDFS from the command-line, **while supporting the same compression and format features** as the aforementioned commands?
`hdfs dfs -put` will seemingly just make a raw copy of a local file to HDFS, without compression or container format change.

Answers suggesting command-line tools for manipulating such formats and compression algorithms are welcome too. I typically see Snappy-compressed data in CompressedStream's but can't figure how to convert a plain-old text file (one datum per line) into such a file from the command-line. I gave a try at [snzip](https://github.com/kubo/snzip) (as suggested in [this askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228956/are-there-any-good-command-line-tools-for-compressing-decompressing-snappy)) as well as [this snappy command-line tool](https://github.com/ma6174/snappy) but couldn't use either of them to generate Hadoop-friendly Snappy files (or read the contents of Snappy files ingested in HDFS using Apache Flume).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is seemingly no reciprocal to `hdfs dfs -text` and WebHDFS also has no support for (de)compression whatsoever, so I ended up writing my own command-line tool in Java for compressing standard input to standard output in Hadoop-friendly Snappy.

Code goes like this:

```
class SnappyCompressor {
    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            CompressionCodecFactory ccf = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);
            CompressionCodec codec =
                ccf.getCodecByClassName(SnappyCodec.class.getName());
            Compressor comp = CodecPool.getCompressor(codec);
            CompressionOutputStream compOut =
                codec.createOutputStream(System.out, comp);
            BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line;
            while( (line=in.readLine()) != null ) {
                compOut.write( line.getBytes() );
                compOut.write( '\n' );
            }
            compOut.finish();
            compOut.close();
        }
        catch( Exception e ) {
            System.err.print("An exception occured: ");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

Run using `hadoop jar <jar path> <class name>`.

Text data compressed this way can be `put` to HDFS (through e.g. `hdfs dfs -put` or using WebHDFS) then read with `hdfs dfs -text`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HDFS NFS, Mount it as a drive and should be able to run linux command to interact.

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html

Comment: And how would that help exactly with file formats and compression modes? I would just have access to raw files just like with `hdfs dfs -put` and `hdfs dfs -get`, right?

Comment: nope, I have a plain-old text file in Unix world (or a program output) and would like to store it as a Snappy file in HDFS. `hdfs dfs -text /path/in/hdfs` makes it possible to read a Snappy file from HDFS as plain-old text in the command line and I wand the opposite operation.

Comment: KiteSDK has the API to write/read compressed data.
Here is the documentation
http://kitesdk.org/docs/1.1.0/apidocs/org/kitesdk/data/CompressionType.html
here is the example
http://eugenedvorkin.com/creating-hadoop-and-impala-friendly-partitioned-data-with-kite-sdk/